# rcppRoll n = number of months instead of obs

Tags: r, data.table

I ran into an issue with the rcppRoll package. I want to use it to sum the value of the past 3 months, however, sometimes there is no data on 1 or more months. The "n = 3" considers the last three observations, rather than the last 3 months. I couldn't find a solid solution, so I am trying my luck here. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

P.S. I prefer to work with data.table and rcpp_roll as my dataset is large and I am familiar with those.

**Code:**

```
library("data.table")
library("RcppRoll")

test = data.table(id = rep(1, 8),date = c("2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11"), value = 1:8)
test = test[, var:= roll_sumr(value, n = 3, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]

   id    date value var
1:  1 2015-01     1  NA
2:  1 2015-02     2  NA
3:  1 2015-03     3   6
4:  1 2015-04     4   9
5:  1 2015-08     5  12
6:  1 2015-09     6  15
7:  1 2015-10     7  18
8:  1 2015-11     8  21
```

**Expected output**

```
prefered_outcome = data.table(id = rep(1, 8),date = c("2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11"), value = 1:8,var = c(NA, NA, 6, 9, NA, NA, 18, 21))
   id    date value var
1:  1 2015-01     1  NA
2:  1 2015-02     2  NA
3:  1 2015-03     3   6
4:  1 2015-04     4   9
5:  1 2015-08     5  NA
6:  1 2015-09     6  NA
7:  1 2015-10     7  18
8:  1 2015-11     8  21
```

Comment: This has nothing (directly) to do with Rcpp so I am removing that tag.

Comment: what happens if there is a row for data for 2015-06? do you still want to show NA for 2015-08 or sum of that row and value of 5 for 2015-08?

Comment: why is the desired result for 2015-08 NA and not 5?

Answer (score 1):

Define `ym` of yearmon class and check if the prior and second prior `ym` are one and two months back and if so use `roll_sumr` and otherwise use NA.

```
library(zoo)

ym <- test[, as.yearmon(date)]
test[, roll := ifelse(ym - 1/12 == shift(ym) & ym - 2/12 == shift(ym, 2),
                      roll_sumr(value, 3, na.rm = TRUE), NA), by = id ]
```

giving:

```
> test
   id    date value roll
1:  1 2015-01     1   NA
2:  1 2015-02     2   NA
3:  1 2015-03     3    6
4:  1 2015-04     4    9
5:  1 2015-08     5   NA
6:  1 2015-09     6   NA
7:  1 2015-10     7   18
8:  1 2015-11     8   21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the missing months first and then performing the function. After that, the added months can be removed again

```
library(data.table)
library("RcppRoll")
library(zoo)
test = data.table(id = rep(1, 8),date = c("2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11"), value = 1:8)
test$date <- as.yearmon(test$date)
allMonths <- seq.Date(from=as.Date(test$date[1]),to=as.Date(test$date[length(test$date)]),by="month")
df2 <- data.frame(date=as.yearmon(allMonths))
df3 <- merge(test,df2, all=TRUE)
df3 <- df3[, var:= roll_sumr(value, n = 3, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
df3
```

Comment: I have considered a similar method, however, it would be rather cumbersome to use the merge as my dataset is already several million obs big.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. What about something like
    `myfun <- function(x){`
     `a <- test[test$date >= as.yearmon(as.Date(x$date) - 3/12) & test$date <= x$date,]`
        `return(sum(a$value))`
     }
      `myfun(test[1])`